# Responsive table not scrolling

Tags: android, css, wordpress, html-table

I have a table in a Wordpress page that I am trying to get working on mobile devices.
On an Android device you can scroll horizontally to view the rest of the content, whereas on an iphone, you cannot scroll horizontally so the prices are not viewable.

Ideally I would like the entire table to be viewable without scrolling but would be happy if you had to scroll to view the content not on the screen. I just need all the content to be viewable somehow.

[Page is here](http://inbeauty2.kpwebservices.net/menu/)

Page code is below:

```
<div align="center">
<table style="width: 60%; padding: 0px; border: 0px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="left">
<table class="footable" style="width: auto; margin: 0px auto;" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">
<h5><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>WAXING</strong></span></h5>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">
<h5><strong>FOR HER</strong></h5>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Eye Brow</td>
<td></td>
<td>$15.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Upper Lip</td>
<td></td>
<td>$10.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Chin</td>
<td></td>
<td>$10.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Bikini</td>
<td></td>
<td>$20.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">G-Bikini</td>
<td></td>
<td>$30.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Under Arm</td>
<td></td>
<td>$15.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Side of Face</td>
<td></td>
<td>$15.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Half Leg</td>
<td></td>
<td>$20.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">¾ Leg</td>
<td></td>
<td>$30.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Full Leg</td>
<td></td>
<td>$40.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Half Arm</td>
<td></td>
<td>$20.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Full Arm</td>
<td></td>
<td>$25.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Buttocks</td>
<td></td>
<td>$20.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Brazilian</td>
<td></td>
<td>$40.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Brow, Lip &amp; Chin</td>
<td></td>
<td>$30.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">
<h5><strong>FOR HIM</strong></h5>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Chest</td>
<td></td>
<td>$30.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Back</td>
<td></td>
<td>$30.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Shoulders</td>
<td></td>
<td>$20.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Full Leg</td>
<td></td>
<td>$40.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Back &amp; Shoulders</td>
<td></td>
<td>$40.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Stomach &amp; Chest</td>
<td></td>
<td>$40.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Neck</td>
<td></td>
<td>$15.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">
<h5><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>THE EYES</strong></span></h5>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Eye Lash Tinting</td>
<td></td>
<td>$20.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Eye Brow Tinting</td>
<td></td>
<td>$15.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Eye Brow Tint &amp; Wax</td>
<td></td>
<td>$25.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Lash + Brow Tint &amp; Wax</td>
<td></td>
<td>$45.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Eye Lash Perm</td>
<td></td>
<td>$45.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Eye Lash Extensions</td>
<td></td>
<td>$150.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Eye Lash Refills</td>
<td>½ Hour</td>
<td>$50.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Eye Lash Refills</td>
<td> 1 Hour</td>
<td>$70.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">
<h5><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>PEDICURE</strong></span></h5>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"><strong>Express Pedicure</strong>
<em>(Soak, File, Exfoliate, Moisturise &amp; Paint)</em></td>
<td>30 Mins</td>
<td>$45.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"><strong>Spa Pedicure</strong>
<em>(Foot bath, Shaping, Cuticle Work, Exfoliation x3,</em>
<em> Foot Massage &amp; Polish)</em></td>
<td>45 Mins</td>
<td>$60.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"><strong>Spa Pedicure Deluxe</strong>
<em>(Our Spa Pedi plus an indulgent paraffin treatment)</em></td>
<td>60 Mins</td>
<td>$80.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Pedicure with Gels or Shellac</td>
<td></td>
<td>$25.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Gel on Toes
<em>(without Pedicure)</em></td>
<td></td>
<td>$50.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Shellac on Toes
<em>(without Pedicure)</em></td>
<td></td>
<td>$40.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">
<h5><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>HANDS &amp; NAILS</strong></span></h5>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">File &amp; Polish</td>
<td></td>
<td>$20.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Shellac Manicure</td>
<td>40 Mins</td>
<td>$40.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Shellac Manicure with Soak off</td>
<td></td>
<td>$45.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"><strong>Manicure</strong>
(A general tidy up of nail length and shape,
Cuticle removal, <em>hand cream &amp; Polish applied)</em></td>
<td>30 Mins</td>
<td>$35.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"><strong>Spa Manicure</strong>
<em>(File, Shaping, Cuticle care, Hand Massage,
Paraffin, Hand cream and p<em>olish applied)</em></em></td>
<td>45 Mins</td>
<td>$50.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">** French Polish</td>
<td>extra</td>
<td>$5.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">
<h5><strong>Acrylics</strong></h5>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Full Set withTips</td>
<td></td>
<td>$65.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Permanent French Acrylics</td>
<td></td>
<td>$75.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Acrylic Refills</td>
<td></td>
<td>$40.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Rebalance</td>
<td></td>
<td>$50.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">
<h5><strong>Bio Sculpture Gel</strong></h5>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Full Set Gels</td>
<td></td>
<td>$65.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Gel Refills</td>
<td></td>
<td>$50.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Repairs</td>
<td> from</td>
<td>$5.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Nail Art (per nail)</td>
<td> from</td>
<td>$5.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Soak Off</td>
<td></td>
<td>$20.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">
<h5><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>THE BODY</strong></span></h5>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Relaxation Massage</td>
<td>30 Mins</td>
<td>$40.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td>60 Mins</td>
<td>$70.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">
<h5><strong>Spray Tanning – Tuscan Tan</strong></h5>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Full Body</td>
<td></td>
<td>$35.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Half Body</td>
<td></td>
<td>$25.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Rapid Full Body (Fast Drying)</td>
<td></td>
<td>$40.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Rapid Half Body</td>
<td></td>
<td>$30.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Rub on Tan</td>
<td></td>
<td>$45.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">
<h5><strong>Make Up</strong></h5>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Napoleon Cosmetics</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Glamification Deluxe</td>
<td>45 Mins</td>
<td>$80.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Glamification Eyes Only 30 Mins</td>
<td></td>
<td>$60.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"><em> ****Redeemable on product****</em></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">
<h5><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>THE FACE</strong></span></h5>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"><strong>Mini Facial</strong>
<em>(Cleanse, Tone, Exfoliating Mask <em>and finishing cream)</em></em></td>
<td>30 Mins</td>
<td>$50.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"><strong>Deep Pore Cleanse</strong>
<em>(For oily, clogged &amp; congested skin. Include<em>s cleanse,
</em></em><em><em>exfoliate, steam, removal of impurities, <em>high frequency
and mask. Application of day, <em>neck and eye cream)</em></em></em></em></td>
<td>45 Mins</td>
<td>$60.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"><strong>In Beauty Classical Facial</strong>
<em>(This treatment is for all skin types and a lovely
i<em>ntroduction to our facials. It will combine ingredients
<em>to heal, nourish, hydrate &amp; firm your skin)</em></em></em></td>
<td>60 Mins</td>
<td>$80.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"><strong>Eye Rejuvenation Treatment</strong>
<em>(Thalgo ‘s Eye Bar treatment uses 5 technologies in 1</em>
<em> mechanical mask which instantly achieves visible &amp;</em>
<em> targeted results around the eye area.  A must for people</em>
<em> who want to target puffiness, dark circles &amp; an instant lift.)</em></td>
<td>30 Mins</td>
<td>$50.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"> ***Add to any of our facials</td>
<td>extra</td>
<td>$20.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">
<h5><strong>Deluxe Facials </strong></h5>
</td>
<td>75 Mins</td>
<td>$115.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Choose From ….</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">       ·<strong>Dehydration </strong> (Hydra Moist)
<em>A super hydrating treatment which saturates your
skin with moisture</em></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">       ·<strong>Anti-aging</strong>   (Collagen)
<em>Smooths and Illuminates Skin</em></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">       ·<strong>Wrinkle Control</strong>  (Hyaluronic)
<em>Smooths &amp; fills deep wrinkles</em></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">       ·<strong>Extreme Deluxe</strong> (Silicium)
<em>Smooths, Fills Wrinkles &amp; lifts your face</em></td>
<td>75 Mins</td>
<td>$129.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">
<h5><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>DIATHERMY</strong></span></h5>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">5 Minutes</td>
<td></td>
<td>$30.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">10 Minutes</td>
<td></td>
<td>$40.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">
<h5><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>ELECTROLYSIS</strong></span></h5>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">5 Minutes</td>
<td></td>
<td>$20.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">10 Minutes</td>
<td></td>
<td>$25.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">15 Minutes</td>
<td></td>
<td>$30.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">For every 5 mins thereafter</td>
<td></td>
<td>$5.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">
<h5><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>MICRODERMABRASION</strong></span></h5>
</td>
<td> 45 mins</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Casual Treatment</td>
<td></td>
<td>$120.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"><strong>Package of 6 treatments</strong></td>
<td>each</td>
<td>$99.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"><em>Microdermabrasion gently removes dead skin cells from the skin
<em>revealing younger, fresher looking skin whilst unclogging pores
<em>&amp; stimulating new cell growth.  Suitable for ALL skin  types.</em></em>
</em></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">
<h5><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>GLYCOLIC PEELS</strong></span></h5>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Glycolic Peel 40%</td>
<td>30 Mins</td>
<td>$65.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"><strong>Package of 3 treatments</strong></td>
<td>each</td>
<td>$55.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"><em>Improves texture of the skin and stimulates collagen renewal.
<em>Improves some types of acne, congestion and blocked pores,
<em>reduces the appearance of fine lines and wrinkles, gives the
skin a <em>fresh and smooth look/ feel, can improve superficial
scarring and <em>irregular pigmentation.  Suitable for ALL skin types.</em></em></em></em>
</em></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">
<h5><strong>Reveal Peel</strong></h5>
</td>
<td>30 Mins</td>
<td>$99.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"><strong>Package of 3 Treatments</strong></td>
<td>each</td>
<td>$88.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"><em>The reveal peel contains a powerful combination of AHAs
(Alpha Hydroxy Acids) <em>and BHAs (Beta Hydroxy Acids), all of
which work together to remove <em>and BHAs (Beta Hydroxy Acids),
all of which work together to remove <em>the outer layer of dead
skin cells, revealing smoother, younger looking skin. <em>This quick
treatment deeply dissolves dead skin, reduces congestion <em>and
stimulates collagen production to improve the radiance and clarity
of the skin.</em></em></em></em></em></em></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">** Add to any of our facials</td>
<td></td>
<td>$35.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">
<h5><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>OXYGEN THERAPY</strong></span></h5>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Rejuvenation Infusion – Hydration</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">One Treatment</td>
<td></td>
<td>$110.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"><strong>Course of 6 Treatments</strong></td>
<td></td>
<td>$590.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"><em>Oxygen Therapy provides a rich concentration of oxygen
<em>directly to the skin improving skin tone, hydration and <em>the
evening of fine lines and wrinkles. Suitable for ALL skin types.</em></em>
</em></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">
<h5><strong>MICRODERMABRASION &amp; OXYGEN THERAPY</strong></h5>
</td>
<td></td>
<td>$160.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">
<h5><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>PAMPER PACKAGES</strong></span></h5>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"><strong>Pure Pleasure  </strong>
<em>1 Hr Relaxation Massage &amp; <em>1 Hr In Beauty Classical Facial</em></em></td>
<td>2 Hrs</td>
<td>$140.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"><strong>Relax &amp; Unwind Package</strong>
<em>1 Hr massage, Spa Pedicure &amp; <em>a Mini Facial</em></em></td>
<td>2 Hrs 15 Min</td>
<td>$165.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"><strong>Heavenly Package</strong>
<em>1 Hour massage, Spa Pedicure <em>Deluxe,
Shellac Manicure &amp; <em>In Beauty Classical Facial</em></em></em></td>
<td>3 Hrs 45 Min</td>
<td>$250.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">
<h5><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Permanent Hair Reduction</strong></span></h5>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Test Patch</td>
<td></td>
<td>$40.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Middle Eyebrow</td>
<td></td>
<td>$30.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Upper Lip</td>
<td></td>
<td>$55.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Chin</td>
<td></td>
<td>$69.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Cheeks</td>
<td></td>
<td>$59.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Sides of Face</td>
<td></td>
<td>$79.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Neck</td>
<td></td>
<td>$99.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Half Face</td>
<td></td>
<td>$159.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Male Beard</td>
<td></td>
<td>$179.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Male Beard including Neck</td>
<td></td>
<td>$199.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Underarms</td>
<td></td>
<td>$89.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">1/2 Arms</td>
<td></td>
<td>$169.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">1/2 Arms including Hands and Fingers</td>
<td></td>
<td>$189.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">3/4 Arms</td>
<td></td>
<td>$199.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">3/4 Arms including Hands and Fingers</td>
<td></td>
<td>$209.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Full Arms</td>
<td></td>
<td>$259.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Full Arms including Hands and Fingers</td>
<td></td>
<td>$279.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Hands and Fingers</td>
<td></td>
<td>$59.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Nipple Area</td>
<td></td>
<td>$49.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Chest or Abdomen</td>
<td></td>
<td>$249.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Chest and Abdomen</td>
<td></td>
<td>$429.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Navel Line</td>
<td></td>
<td>$89.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Back - Upper or Lower</td>
<td></td>
<td>$199.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Back - Full</td>
<td></td>
<td>$349.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Shoulders and Back of neck</td>
<td></td>
<td>$179.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Bikini Line</td>
<td></td>
<td>$99.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Extended Bikini</td>
<td></td>
<td>$109.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Brazilian</td>
<td></td>
<td>$129.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Brazilian Extended</td>
<td></td>
<td>$159.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Buttocks</td>
<td></td>
<td>$159.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Lower Legs</td>
<td></td>
<td>$269.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Lower Legs including Knees and Feet</td>
<td></td>
<td>$299.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Legs - Upper Thigh</td>
<td></td>
<td>$349.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Full Legs</td>
<td></td>
<td>$509.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Full Legs including Feet</td>
<td></td>
<td>$539.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Full Legs including Bikini</td>
<td></td>
<td>$559.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Feet and Toes</td>
<td></td>
<td>$49.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Shave @ Treatment</td>
<td></td>
<td>$25.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">
<h5><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>SPECIALS</strong></span></h5>
</td>
<td height="21"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Brazilian &amp; Underarm</td>
<td></td>
<td>$159.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Lip &amp; Chin</td>
<td></td>
<td>$99.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">
<h5><strong>Buy 6 Treatments</strong></h5>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Brazilian</td>
<td></td>
<td>$599.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Upper Lip</td>
<td></td>
<td>$299.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Underarms</td>
<td></td>
<td>$449.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Lower Legs</td>
<td></td>
<td>$1,199.00</td>
</tr>
<tr align="right">
<td align="left">Lower Legs including Knees and Feet</td>
<td></td>
<td>$1,299.00</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Cheers,
kp

Comment: My first suggestion might be to try using a [css media query](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries) when your down to a small mobile device width and then try applying [table-layout: fixed;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) to your table styling and set a width on the table to match the mobile device? so that it forces all your content to fit inside a small table.. this will require different widths depending on the orientation too.. which can also be done with media queries.

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

// rest of your XML 

</ScrollView>
```